# Implement a Spring Base RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm new with Spring and Spring-boot.

I have to implement some rest services.

I have, in general, two different types of these rest service and I would like to create two different BaseController to implement the common logic that I'll have for the other specific sub-controllers.

For example. I would like to have a base controller (to map the base url `/api/v1/typeA/`) without (probably) any specific services (GET, POST, etc)

And I would like to extend this base controller for each sub-controllers

For example:

1. ControllerA1 extends BaseControllerA     (`/api/v1/typeA/EntityA1`)
   with GET, POST, etc methods
2. ControllerA2 extends BaseControllerA    (`/api/v1/typeA/EntityA2`)
   with GET, POST, etc methods

I would like to have this because, probably I need some commons logics from each sub controllers (for example Authorization logics, validations logic, ...)

In practically, I would like to extend a BaseController and each method will inherit shared logic.

I would like, if it possible, to prepare the validated objects when I will process a request into a sub-controller. I mean: probably when I will validate a request I will need to make some queries to retrieve some data. If the validation will be done I would like to inject this data into a request and I will have access on it into the specific sub-controller (without to make the same queries)

Can you suggest me some example or information to implement this? Any suggestion about my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `BaseController`. I think you need a `Filter` where you can implement custom authorization logic. You can add this filter to the request chain and that way you'll only need to implement that logic once.

Here is are some examples of implementing a `Filter`:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter
- https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5

`Filter`'s are not limited to implementing authorization logic. You can also add specific logic for let's say logging.